# Googletest/gtets: fatal error: gtest.h: No such file or directory

Tags: unit-testing, testing, googletest, googlemock

I have built gtest from source. I have created static libraries. But When i am running my tests, it is giving error that is 'fatal error: gtest.h: No such file or directory'. I have included the path. gtest.h is present in include/gtest folder. I do not know why i am getting this error. Can you help me?

Comment: How do you compile your code?

Comment: g++ -I/../external/include test.cpp -o tests -L../external/lib -lgtest -lgtest_main -lpthread

Comment: `gtest.h` does not exist in `/../external/include`. It exists in `/../external/include/gtest`. So compile with `-I/../external/include/gtest`

Comment: Or change your include to `#include <gtest/gtest.h>`, that's more common option. You may also need to update your libraries path (`-L` option), if after compilation you would get "*unresolved reference to...*" linker errors